# As I get the value of an option of a select ? symfony2

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

I have something like this in my view:

```
<form .....>
<select>
     <option value="five">5</option>
     <option value="ten">10</option>
     <option value="fifteen">15</option>
</select>
</form>
```

As I do in the controller to take the values ​​of the options?
PD: It is a manual select , do not use types that actually genre with jquery .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your select a name, so it will be submitted in the form.

```
<select name="whatever">
```

Then in PHP, it will be in

```
$_POST['whatever'];
```

Comment: Yes I understand. But then how do I get the value of the option that the user chose ?? Thank you.

Comment: That is the value of the option they chose. Your form has to also have `method="post"`

Comment: So, there's the `value` which in your case is five, ten, fifteen. Then there's the option's text which is your 5, 10, 15. The form will only submit the `value`, not the text.

Comment: If you are using symfony and as the question has symfony tagged better use `$request->request->get('select_name')` to get the post values ($request is instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request). If you are using framework better follow the approach suggested by it.

Comment: I agree @SanThapa, I think the problem was the OP didn't have a name, or POST. So it still wouldn't have worked.

Comment: @Jessica I was just supporting your answer with added suggestion.